# How can i start the invoke function until i click one object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, invoke

In my scene design, i have a cube and i want to click the cube to start the game. In the Start() function, i have two invoke function, but i don't know how to invoke them until i clicked the cube. Actually

Currently, my Start function is shown as below. And i tried to use a IEnumerator function to solve this. Also shown as below.  And in another script which is in the Cube object, i wanna change the `static bool star`t in other script when `OnMouseDown()`.

```
public class Progress : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public bool start = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Begin());
        Invoke("startCycle", 3);
        Invoke("startCycle", 15);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        //StartCoroutine(Begin());
        Invoke("startCycle", 3);
        Invoke("startCycle", 15);
    }


   IEnumerator Begin()
   {
        while(!start){
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CursorClick : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Progress.start = true;
    }
}
```

However, it just doesn't work, the invoke still will happen even though i didn't clicked the cube. Plz help!

Comment: Sorry, thats the typo, there is only one Start(). startCycle is the function that i need to implemented (like expand the sphere and shrink stuff). should i just change yield return null; into yield return new WaitUntil(start);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StartCoroutine(Begin());
```

starts the `Begin()` Coroutine but doesn't wait for it to finish. Since your `Start` is defined as `void` it simply runs through all the code without waiting for anything.

---

Either move the calls you want to wait with into the coroutine and for better readability use [`WaitUntil`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html) like

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Begin());
}

private IEnumertor Begin()
{
    return new WaitUntil(() => start);

    Invoke("startCycle", 3);
    Invoke("startCycle", 15);
}
```

Or  - though it is not really documented - you can simply directly convert the `Start` itself into a Coroutine

```
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    return new WaitUntil(() => start);

    Invoke("startCycle", 3);
    Invoke("startCycle", 15);
}
```

If `Start` is implemented as `IEnumertor` Unity internally automatically calls it as a Coroutine. You can actually see it in the example for [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html)

Comment: "you can simply directly convert the Start itself into a Coroutine". That is a really useful trick and I am kind of astonished I don't see that more often on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Ruzihm anyway thanks for the comment! Since you might not be the only one I added it to the answer ;)

Comment: For the "return new WaitUntil(start);" it said "cannot convert bool into system.func<bool>", it means i cannot use start in ( ).

Comment: @ChenJi yeah sorry for that. I always forget ^^ You have to use a lambda expression (updated the answer) or a method like `private bool CanStart() { return start; }` then you could go `WaitUntil(CanStart);`

Comment: @Ruzihm sorry .. I just tested it and saw that I lied :D .. only the documentation made it look like Start would finish befor Update runs but nope ... It is always running parallel to Update ... would have been a nice feature though ... in general Coroutines `yield` is run after `Update`